# Проблема кнопки "facebook like"

Tags: browsers, html, javascript, facebook-api

Проблема вот в чем: чтобы перейти назад со страницы на которой установлена данная кнопка, нужно нажать два раза кнопку назад.

**Как это исправить?**

Вот **[тут](http://cms.unotes.ru)** наглядный пример.

> Переходим по ссылке и пытаемся в один клик перейти назад.

**Браузер:** *ПРЕДПОСЛЕДНЯЯ* Opera.

Comment: все хорошо работает по одному клику (последняя opera)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Вашем примере у меня все работает нормально (Opera 12.0). Но действительно были "чудеса" в Опере, когда для возвращения назад приходилось нажимать два - три раза (для примера сайт новостей lb.ua - периодически "чудит"). P.S. Мышь, точпад нормальные.